# Rails test validates_associated on model spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, rails-activerecord

Is there an equivalent to

```
  it { should validate...


  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(
```

etc for

```
 validates_associated
```

Something like,

```
it { should validate_associate(:associated_model_object)
```

except, you know, functional.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems others have thought about it: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/133

Comment: So that would make the answer no then? Any good way to simulate this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
it "should validate associate_model_object" do
  m = Model.new(valid_params)
  m.associated_models.build(invalid_params)
  m.save.should eq(false)
end
```

Replace the middle line with this if you're coming from the other direction:

```
m.build_associated_model(invalid_params)
```

Comment: in case associated model is named `Template` it should be written:
`m.build_template(...valid/invalid_params here...)`

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a built-in matcher for validates_associated, I wrote this:

```
it { is_expected.not_to validate_presence_of(:child) }

context 'when child is present' do
  let(:child) { FactoryBot.create(:child) }
  before { subject.child = child }
  it { is_expected.to be_valid }

  context 'when child is present but not valid' do
    before { child.age = -1 }
    it { is_expected.not_to be_valid }
  end
end
```

This line: `before { child.age = -1 }` requires some knowledge of `Child`'s validations. That is not ideal from the context of `Parent`'s unit test, but that certainly isn't the worst programming sin I've ever made.